# ¿Cómo dejar una imagen al 100% de ancho con Boostrap 4?

Tags: css, html5, css3

estoy haciendo un landing para una empresa con Boostrap 4 ... ya la tengo lista en la siguiente URL: [landing](https://acrip.org/eldiadelejecutivo/) y como pueden ver la imagen de los personajes debe estar al 100% de la pantalla.

Esto yo lo soluciono con este esilo:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Pero cuando lo uso me genera un espacio en la parte derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el responsive también se ve mas grande ese espacio

GRACIAS

Comment: ¿Con qué navegador estás usándolo? Yo he entrado en la página que dices y se ve correctamente.

Comment: Hola,tines razón .... pruebas con este enlace ... https://elgatodiego.com/clientes/acrip/ .... revisando bien es que ese espacio se presenta cuando se hace scroll hacia abajo .... si vuelvo a darle scroll hacia arriba desaparece el espacio

Answer (score 2):

No sé como tienes puesta la imagen, si como background o img en el html.

Si es como background así lo corregirás:

```
.CLASEDELAIMG{background-size:cover; background-repeat: no-repeat}
```

Si es como img en el html:

```
.CLASEDELAIMG{width:100vw;}
```

espero que te haya podido resultar de ayuda.

Comment: tiene razon, con `width: 100vw;` arreglas el problema
pero considera utilizar `box-sizing: border-box;` para que encaje perfectamente 